# readObject method only reads the first object it receives

Tags: java

Just to give the background of my issue; I'm writing a client server application. when a client initially connects, the server accesses the database and send all the items in a particular table to the client by writing the objects to an objectoutputstream in a for loop.

The issue is, the client reads only the first object that is being sent. Even if I create a new object and send it to the server for verification the client does not pick it up when the server sends it back after inserting to database... extract from code:

Server:

```
public void loadClients()
{

    ArrayList <Client> list = dBCon.loadClients();
    try
    {
        for (int i =0; i<list.size();i++)
        {
            sendtoClient(list.get(i));
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void sendtoClient(Object obj) throws IOException
{
    _out.writeObject(obj);
    _out.flush();
    _out.reset();

}
```

Client:

```
socket = new Socket("localhost", 4447);
ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
Object objIn = ois.readObject();
Client client = (Client)objIn;
switch(client.actionType)
{
    case ("ADD"):
    {
        if(clientFrame.tbDeals!=null)
        {
            clientFrame.tbDeals.addClient(client);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            clientList.add(client);
            System.out.println(client.clientName);
            break;

        }
    }

}
```

Edit: I have tried with a while loop on the client side as well. then ois.available() returns 0....

Comment: You're reading *exactly* one object on the client side. Why would you expect there to be more than one? Yes, you use a `while` loop, and no, you rarely if ever use `available()` - it doesn't do what you think it does in most cases. Basic IO in Java is blocking.

Comment: available() isn't a valid test for end of stream. See the Javadoc. It isn't much use for anything else either.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, I actually worked it out myself after asking the question. I created another wrapper class with an object array in it and included all the objects that I originally needed to send in an instance of the wrapper class. now it is working fine!!! For anyone else who come across this issue: Don't try to send objects separately as I did, but put them in an array and serialize the array. TY very much for all the people who answered!

Comment: The real issue here is that your statement 'I create a new object' is false. You didn't create a new object, you re-populated an existing object, and then *re*-sent it, so the Serialization 'handle' mechanism kicked in. If you really had created a new object, it would have worked. Or if you had used writeUnshared(), or reset().

Answer (score 3):

You're reading *exactly* one object on the client side. That's all you're going to get.

`available()` is rarely if ever used when doing basic IO in Java, and generally isn't going to do what you think it does.

Reading from a `ObjectInputStream` is blocking, just like all other basic Java IO. Using `readObject()` you will either get an object, or an exception [as noted in the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject%28%29)

The most simplistic example of how you would handle this in a loop if you have no idea the number of objects you'll be receiving and expect the connection to stay open is:

```
while (true) {

    try {
        Object o = ois.readObject();
        /// do something with the object you just read
    } catch ( EOFException e) {
        System.out.println("remote connection closed!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, but there is no need for betting. You should catch EOFException separately, when it is a dead certainty.

Comment: @EJP - I was going off the Javadoc. Does it throw an `EOFException` explicitly or wrapped in an `IOEXception`?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'explicitly', but every readXXX() method except readLine() throws EOFException at end of stream. readLine() returns null. The plain read() methods return -1, for completeness.

Comment: (I did a quick edit to clarify "explicitly") Basically ... I never use Java's built in serialization, so I'm just reading Javadocs on this one and it doesn't list EOFException on readObject- I'm guessing because it's a subclass now that I think about it, duh.

Comment: @EJP Sorry - it's obviously past my bedtime. It was at least a good answer :-D